# Export Crystal Report to Text File - No RTF File

Tags: asp.net, file, text, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report that comes with VS 2005. I need to Export the Crystal Report To Text File. What's the way to do it.

Comment: The more I use the Crystal API, the more I dislike it.  This question deserves an answer.  I wish I had one better than the one I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they've taken away that [enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms226443(VS.80).aspx) for some reason.  I suppose you could loop through the underlying recordset, and dump the contents into a text file yourself.  What a PITA though...

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you will get to a text file is to export as csv.

ExportFormatType.CharacterSeparatedValues

Now, the thing that sucks about this is if the report is designed to look good (with page footers, headers, etc) the csv file will contain all that. So you would need to make a minimal report to get a good csv export. Which really almost makes it seem more logical to dump to text file yourself.

Comment: looking at JosephStyons link I'm not sure if this csv exporttype is in VS 2005 crystal. I'm using cr XI...